# Get more then 2000 records in listview API

Tags: rest-api

My Contact Listview has 5000 records and I want to get all the records using Listview API . I can use offset upto 2000 which means I can query 4000 in total . Is there any other way I can get all 5000 records. In query REST API SF has nextRecordsUrl. but here in [listview API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_listviewresults.htm) it does not return that to further get remaining records.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to use the Listview resource of the REST API? Simply performing a regular ol' query through the REST API should be able to get you the same data, but with fewer restrictions.

Comment: Yes.. The reason is I have only listview id not a where condition .. so as long as I can get the desired result I can use query REST call

Comment: Surely you should be able to translate the criteria for displaying records in the list view into a `WHERE` clause, no? Yes, it'd be an inconvenience (especially if the listview's criteria ever changed), but there doesn't seem to be a way around the listView resource's limitations here.

Comment: Yeah.. I know .. I don't want that . I had this implementation so that I just need to change Listview in SF and it is reflected on API result side. Thanks